# React check files in src without test files

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, devops

Is it possible to check files inside **src** without test(unit) files in React with typescript, jest?

Eg:
We have files like below
src/button.tsx
src/dropdwon.tsx

tests/button.test.tsx
**Missed to add dropdown.test.tsx**
On running this `jest`, shows only src/button.tsx is covered(expected).
but, Is there any way to check to throw error to add test file for "dropdown.tsx"?
Also to check all files inside src folder?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the following config in your jest configuration to find the test coverage of all the files in your main folder.

collectCoverageFrom" : ["app/**/*.js"],

Please refer the below link for further understanding.

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1211

Comment: I have folder name as src, So with this [src/**/*.jsx] it works, Thanks.